# Filtering Netcat results in a Bash script

Tags: bash, filter, netcat

I am trying to write a script that connects to a list of IPs on port 53 - and I want the result to return only open ports. Here is the script I am running below - I have tried grepping and cutting the output but im not sure I am doing this correctly - I cant seem to pipe the script results to a text file either.

```
#!/bin/bash

for ip in $(seq 200 254); do
    nc -v 192.168.11.$ip 53 &
done
```

I apologise for its simplicity I am new - and if the solution is elsewhere

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check for the command's exit code, it should be zero for a successful connection. Also use the *-z* option to drop the connection once it has been established.

```
#!/bin/bash

for ip in $(seq 200 254); do
    nc -z 192.168.11.$ip 53
    if [ $? -eq 0 ]; then
        echo "Hit: 192.168.11.$ip"
    fi
done
```

If you were using nmap instead of netcat, you could have used this:

```
nmap 192.168.11.200-254 -p 53
```

PS. If you're trying to determine which hosts run DNS server, you should scan for open 53/udp, not 53/tcp (option *-u* in netcat)

Comment: Also check for fpdns tool, it comes quite handy for DNS fingerprinting. http://linux.die.net/man/1/fpdns

Comment: `if nc -z 192.168.11.$ip 53; then echo...; fi`. No need to check `$?` explicitly.

Answer (score 0):

If you want all the output of a command to go to a file use `&>`. In your example you could use:

```
#!/bin/bash

for ip in $(seq 200 254); do
    nc -v 192.168.11.$ip 53 &>> myFile
done
```

Then you can manipulate (grep, sed, awk, etc.) `myFile` however you want.